# Paper on the use of probability theory in finance?

Tags: probability

I have taken probability theory course in college and want to see how it is used practically in finance.

What papers should I read? I want it to be not too difficult (undergraduate probability theory course level would be great)

Comment: What about this one: https://dx.doi.org/10.2307%2F3215299

Comment: In my experience, probability theory like risk neutral measure is only used in academic.

Comment: Can you please list some of the topics you've covered: e.g. Probability measures, Lebesgue integration, Ito's lemma, Girsanov's theorem, HJB equation, etc. Probability theory is still a broad topic (not even including statistics!), and can be applied in areas including Monte Carlo applications in financial engineering, interest rate modelling in fixed income, stochastic control in optimisation and HFT, etc.

Answer (score 1):

$\,\,\,$Generally, Finance involve some degree of uncertainty, so we need to use probabilistic reasoning in order to make a sound decision. Nowadays, we need to apply modern probability in each part of finance and this issue is too widespread.However, I introduce some useful articles and books:

1. [Levy processes: From probability to finance and quantum groups](http://www.ams.org/notices/200411/fea-applebaum.pdf)
2. [The Laplace Distribution and Generalizations: A Revisit with Applications to Communications, Economics, Engineering, and Finance](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780817641665)
3. [Recovering Probability Distributions from Option Prices](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1540-6261.1996.tb05219.x/full)
4. [The application of continuous-time random walks in finance and economics](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378437105012069)
5. [Large Deviations of Heavy-Tailed Random Sums with Applications in Insurance and Finance](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3215371?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)
6. [Stable Distributions: Probability, Inference, and Applications in Finance:A Survey, and a Review of Recent Results](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-010-1842-5_8)